# rust error with question mark operator "the trait bound is not satisfied"

Tags: rust

```
use std::io;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut csv = File::open("Item.csv")?;
}
```

this is some part of my code, and I've got error:

```
   Compiling eracsv v0.1.0 (file:///C:/Users/jwm/Project/eracsv)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `(): std::ops::Try` is not satisfied
 --> src\main.rs:
  |
  |     let mut csv = File::open("Item.csv")?;
  |                   -----------------------
  |                   |
  |                   the `?` operator can only be used in a function that returns `Result` (or another type that implements `std::ops::Try`)
  |                   in this macro invocation
  |
  = help: the trait `std::ops::Try` is not implemented for `()`
  = note: required by `std::ops::Try::from_error`
```

I have deal with both rustc 1.19 stable and 1.22 nightly and both discharging same error.

but, this is exactly same code as [rust doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/#read-and-write), isn't it? It is explicitly mentioned that File::open() function returns result .

I am curious why ? operator makes compile error while unwrap() doesn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What the error message is actually telling you is you're using the `?` operator inside of a function that returns `()` (this being the `main` function). The `?` operator propagates errors upwards, but it can only do that if the function it's used in actually has a compatible return type that can represent that error.

Or in other words, you can only use it in a function that itself is returning a `Result` (with a compatible error type). Your `main` does not return a `Result`, so you cannot use the `?` operator inside of it.

You may also be interested in [RFC 1937](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1937-ques-in-main.md), which would allow the use of `?` in `main` (by allowing you to declare that `main` returns a `Result`).

Comment: I haven't catched that try statement in rust returns Result! Thanks!